# Why is my color being darkened when printed?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, cmyk

I am creating a logo and I am using Pantone 638U in Illustrator.  I know Pantone has to be premixed but I just wanted to test print on my printer in CMYK.  So I converted it to cmyk which is `C83 M0 Y10 K0`.  My document is in CMYK mode and I am using `View > proof colors`.  Here is a photo of what result I am getting.  The left is on screen and the right is (approximately) the printed result.

[image]

Comment: Is this the only color you are having an issue with? How about the rest?

Comment: Its a one color logo with black text.  The text comes out fine and crisp, but the logo comes out more navy blue than teal/sky blue.

Comment: Something you are using is absolutely not calibrated correctly. http://i.stack.imgur.com/Att2L.jpg

Comment: I would look into color calibration and invest in a Pantone book.

Comment: Try sending an RGB file to your printer. Most end-user inkjet printers are confused when you send them CMYK data.

Comment: So we talking about "printed" as in "printed on my inkjet" instead of "offset press"? It can be a little ambiguous.

Comment: I tries RGB and still the same thing.  The picture you shared Scott would be completely acceptable to me.  I wish I could get that.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few issues here:

1. Pantone colors are spot colors. They are custom mixes. Not every Pantone color can be replicated in CMYK. As such, there will be a shift when converting from Pantone to CMYK.
2. Screens are projected light. Ink is reflective light. Screens and Ink can't replicate all the same colors. So what you see on screen isn't always what you will see on press.
3. Your screen may not be calibrated to make even a close approximation of what you'd see in print. Few are.